# does the "By + gerund" clause have a passive meaning?

Tags: meaning-in-context, clauses, interpretation

I have a sentence similar to this one:

> Hibernate can validate your schema by setting the Hibernate property to `validate`

Does it imply that Hibernate validates this schema **because it (Hibernate) set the property** or does "by setting the property" mean that **if this action is done**?
Not sure if the context matters here, but this is used in the context of a step-by-step tutorial.

I ended up rephrasing it to make it clear that the user has to enable it, but I'm curious how can the above sentence be interpreted.

Comment: Hi. If it's user-initiated, it might have been clearer to  say "if you set" instead of "by setting", but this might just be nit-picking.  I think most would understand "by setting" from the context to mean a user-initiated setting.

Comment: The confusion here arises because the two actions have different agents— **Hibernate** can validate, and [implicitly] **you** do the setting—but by the standard patterns of idiomatic English, in sentences of the form “*A* can *X* by *Y*-ing,” the implied grammatical subject of the verb *Y* is *A*. For this reason, composition teachers would have the sentence rewritten.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is poorly worded.
I strongly suspect that what the writer meant was, "Hibernate can validate your schema IF YOU SET the Hibernate property to validate". Or better, "Set the Hibernate property to validate to cause Hibernate to validate your schema."
As worded, the only subject in the sentence is Hibernate, so taken literally the sentence says that Hibernate sets the property. Which is very unlikely to be the intended meaning.
It occurs to me that learning a new language could be made more difficult because you can't always rely on even fluent speakers being strictly correct all the time! Sometimes people get sloppy.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the property to 'validate' is the *way* it validates the schema - the method it uses.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no passive in that sentence.

The structure "by X" is used in passive sentences to indicate who/what did the action of the main verb, but in this sentence, there's no passive structure (be-verb + past participle) and the "by X" structure indicates the *method* for doing something, not who/what did it.